# R jsonlite tojson producing .1 on duplicate key names

Tags: r, jsonlite

I have the following R structure

```
list(Message = list(MessageType = "WARNING", MessageSubType = "USERNAME", 
    MessageID = "105"), Message = list(MessageType = "WARNING", 
    MessageSubType = "PASSWORD", MessageID = "106"))
```

I want to convert it to this using `jsonlite::toJSON(auto_unbox = T)`

```
{"Message":{"MessageType":"WARNING","MessageSubType":"USERNAME","MessageID":"105"},"Message_1":{"MessageType":"WARNING","MessageSubType":"PASSWORD","MessageID":"106"}}
```

However, instead of "Message_1" jsonlite increments with "Message.1".

The kicker: This could be in multiple structures, so I need something that can be repeatable regardless of the key names. Not sure if `jsonlite::toJSON()` can take an argument to tell it to behave like the desired output above. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If we need to change the duplicate names from the default option `.1`, `.2` etc,  use

```
names(lst1) <- make.unique(names(lst1), sep="_")
```

Now, apply the `toJSON`

```
jsonlite::toJSON(lst1, auto_unbox = TRUE)
#{"Message":{"MessageType":"WARNING","MessageSubType":"USERNAME","MessageID":"105"},"Message_1":{"MessageType":"WARNING","MessageSubType":"PASSWORD","MessageID":"106"}}
```

---

Essentially, the duplicate names are changed with `make.unique` when it calls `data.frame` and the default option is `sep="."`

> make.unique(names, sep = ".")

#### data

```
lst1 <- list(Message = list(MessageType = "WARNING", MessageSubType = "USERNAME", 
    MessageID = "105"), Message = list(MessageType = "WARNING", 
    MessageSubType = "PASSWORD", MessageID = "106"))
```

Comment: this looks good. I'm trying to see if jsonlite would allow an optional param to pass to its usage of make.unique. in lieu of that, I'll fork and modify to my own use, then PR back to the main project.

Comment: I've opened a PR for this. https://github.com/jeroen/jsonlite/pull/340